# How to remove first two and last two characters from each label in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, expression

My too long labels take up too much space in regard to the small counties polygons.
I want to remove first two and the last two characters from each single label.
Currently the labels on the map look like this:
PL1607000 PL1816000 LV801200 LT029900 EE700000 etc.

Because in each single label the first two characters are two-letter country code, and the last two characters always two zeros, to make map more clean I want my labels like this:
16070 18160 8012 0299 7000 etc.

I use Maplex Label Engine. My label field is CTYCode, What expression should I type in Label expression dialog box?
Is it possible to also make stacked labels from this labels? I want to the first two characters were at the top, and the rest at the bottom. Like this:

16       18     80    02   70 

070    160    12    99   00




  etc.

How do I write two different expressions. With and without stacking labels, I do not know about programming at all and I would not know how to change the expression.

Comment: I corrected text and i think its ok now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the python parser and a simple bit of string slicing.

In the label expression dialog ensure Advanced is ticked on and the parser is set to python as shown below:

[image: Label expression]

The code in the expression box is this:

```py
def FindLabel ( [CTYCode] ):
  label = [CTYCode]
  strippedtext = label[2:-2]    # Slice off the first and last 2 characters
  start = strippedtext[:2]      # Extract or "slice" off first 2 characters
  end = strippedtext[2:]        # Extract all characters after the second
  newlabel = start + "\n" + end # Build new label inserting special newline character
  return newlabel
```

If you don't want them on separate lines simple exclude the new line character where you build the `newlabel`.